# Looking for second opinion on checking that attribute in data frame is unique using r

Tags: r

Check whether attribute name in city is unique (i.e. each city has a different name).  data_frame is city with a column called name.

```
length(unique(city$name))
rapply(city,function(name)length(unique(name)))
unique(city$name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple options are available in R.Apart from your mentioned function.

dplyr

duplicated

Comment: Ok, so when someone on this site is looking for the same answer they can go to this question.